# How to integrate dynamic routes in Docusaurus with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docusaurus

I have a website made with Docusaurus v2 that currently contains documentation. However, I would like to add a page of a list of workflows where if a workflow in the list is clicked, the user would be shown a page of additional details of that workflow. For now it seems `docusaurus.config`  seems to be handling most of the routing, but is there a way I can add a dynamic route like `/workflows/:id`? I made a separate standalone app which had a Router object and it worked if my App.js looks like this:

```
// App.js
import Navigation from './Navigation'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
  <Router>
    <Navigation />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route>
      <Route path="/workflows" exact component={Workflows}></Route>
      <Route path="/workflows/:id" component={WorkflowItem}></Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
  )
}
```

Is it possible to add the Router somewhere in Docusaurus?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by creating a simple plugin to add my own custom routes. Documentation [here](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/using-plugins#creating-plugins).

Let's call the plugin `plugin-dynamic-routes`.

```js
// {SITE_ROOT_DIR}/plugin-dynamic-routes/index.js

module.exports = function (context, options) {
    return {
        name: 'plugin-dynamic-routes',

        async contentLoaded({ content, actions }) {
            const { routes } = options
            const { addRoute } = actions

            routes.map(route => addRoute(route))
        }
    }
}
```

```js
// docusaurus.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'plugin-dynamic-routes'),
            { // this is the options object passed to the plugin
                routes: [
                    { // using Route schema from react-router
                        path: '/workflows',
                        exact: false, // this is needed for sub-routes to match!
                        component: '@site/path/to/component/App'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    ],
}
```

You may be able to use the above method to configure sub-routes as well but I haven't tried it. For the custom page, all you need is the `Switch` component (you are technically using nested routes at this point). The `Layout` component is there to integrate the page into the rest of the Docusaurus site.

```js
// App.js

import React from 'react'
import Layout from '@theme/Layout'
import { Switch, Route, useRouteMatch } from '@docusaurus/router'

function App() {
    let match = useRouteMatch()

    return (
        <Layout title="Page Title">
            <Switch>
                <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={WorkflowItem} />
                <Route path={match.path} component={Workflows} />
            </Switch>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

Comment: `component: '@site/App'`
throw an Error
`./.docusaurus/registry.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@site/App' in '/Users/katopz/git/katopz/my-website/.docusaurus'`
I've `/src/App.jsx` there but still get an error.
What exactly to fill in there?

Comment: I was able to use `"../src/..."` no `.tsx`/`.js` needed